# Laggy UITableView scrolling because of CAShapeLayer (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, uitableview, cashapelayer

I have a UITableView within a UIView, and it is made up of custom cells defined by the following class:

```
class CustomAddFriendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameLbl: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var AddFriendBtn: UIButton!
}
```

Within the ViewController's `tableview(_:cellForRowAt:)` method I call the following function to layout the cell's ProfileImg:

```
private func layoutProfilePics(with cell:CustomAddFriendTableViewCell) {
    //create gradient
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: cell.ProfileImg.frame.size)
    gradient.colors = [Colors.blueGreen.cgColor, Colors.yellow.cgColor]

    //create gradient mask
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 3
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: cell.ProfileImg.bounds).cgPath // commenting this out makes lag go away
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor // commenting this out makes lag go away
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    cell.ProfileImg.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.ProfileImg.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.ProfileImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.ProfileImg.layer.cornerRadius = cell.ProfileImg.bounds.size.width/2.0
    cell.ProfileImg.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

}
```

This code causes `ProfileImg` to be a circle and have a border with a blue-green gradient.
The two lines with comments next to them make the scrolling very smooth (meaning the gradient is not what is causing the lag), so I assume that rendering the CAShapeLayer (specifically the stroke) is causing the problem (hence the question title). What can I do to improve the tableview's scrolling performance?

Also, I am not sure if this is an XCode bug or if it has something to do with my problem, but in the Project Navigator's Instruments pane, when I run the app and scroll the laggy UITableView, the FPS does not reflect the lag, even though I can clearly tell that it is very laggy. In fact, there are no noticeable differences in any of the components in the pane (CPU, Memory, Energy Impact, etc.).

**Update:**

I tried moving the `layoutProfilePics(with:)` function into the `CustomAddFriendTableViewCell`'s `prepareForReuse()` function and I also tried putting `layoutProfilePics(with:)` in its `layoutSubviews()` function but neither of them improved the scrolling.

Comment: You're supposed to change the content(s) in `tableview(_:cellForRowAt:)`. That method of yours makes a good candidate when creating cell, not when dequeuing.

Comment: I tried moving the function to the custom cell's class's `layoutSubviews()` function and also tried moving it to the custom cell's class's `prepareForReuse()` function but neither improved the tableivew's scrolling performance.

Comment: Have you ensured that you only add these layers to each cell once? Remember that cells are reused, and any layers you add to the cell on first use will still be there when it is reused, unless you remove them.

Comment: @robmayoff The method is called in `tableview(_:cellForRowAt:)`, and a reusable cell is dequeued in that tableview function, so every time a cell is created, its profile picture is laid out via the `layoutProfilePics(with:)` function. Since the `layoutProfilePics(with:)` function is only called in one location (`tableview(_:cellForRowAt:)`), there is no reason it would be called multiple times for the same cell. Even if the tableview's data is reloaded, each cell would be recreated and the layout function would be called once for each cell.

Comment: Edit your question to include your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` source code.

Comment: How laggy your animation is compared to this: https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-343da6d59f.gif

Comment: @MuhammadHassan The link does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is meant to be called once for each cell and for that, it shouldn't be called in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. Try moving that code to `awakeFromNib()` and if you're using a nib for your custom cell, use the following code in `viewDidLoad()` to load the the outlets:

```
let addFriendCellNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomAddFriendTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(addFriendCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "addFriendCell")
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: This works. Thank you! Also, do you know why the Instruments were not showing any data that you normally see when there is lag?

Comment: Not sure what data you're referring. The lag was due to your UI getting sizeable during scrolling; adding a layer each time a cell is dequeued.

Comment: The data I'm referring to is the CPU performance, FPS, Memory, etc. that are on the 6th tab in the Project Navigator Pane in XCode. And what do you mean by sizeable?

Comment: I'm getting CPU and memory benchmark values if that's what you mean. By sizable, I meant that you were adding sublayers to `ProfileImg` and after few seconds, animation starts to get laggy. If you print sublayers count, it'd keep increasing, making your UI complex and large.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. And yeah, I meant the CPU and FPS benchmark values weren't reflecting the lag I was seeing when scrolling. They looked normal (for example, it said I was getting ~60 FPS even though I could tell there was a lot of lag when scrolling).